# What is the form_key used for?

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, security, form-key, csrf

I really don't understand the `form_key` feature. I have found several sites asking and dealing with issues about the `form_key` but none explained the reason for it's existence.

Everyone just worked around this "security feature" [e.g. this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19546557/3623574)

Can anybody explain what the `form_key` is used for?

---

EDIT:
ok, I get the CSRF Vector for changing user data or anything beyond the cart and even the checkout.
But what could the possible attack on the cart be?!

Comment: For your follow-up question, see: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70949/why-is-csrf-protection-needed-for-add-to-cart?lq=1

Comment: it simply states that there is no viable attack on that particular action and and it's rather more ideological than well thought of.
But this information helps me though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It prevents [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)

> Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) is an attack which forces an end user to execute unwanted actions on a web application in which he/she is currently authenticated. CSRF attacks specifically target state-changing requests, not theft of data, since the attacker has no way to see the response to the forged request. With a little help of social engineering (like sending a link via email/chat), **an attacker may trick the users of a web application into executing actions of the attacker's choosing**. If the victim is a normal user, a successful CSRF attack can force the user to perform state changing requests like transfering funds, changing their email address, etc. If the victim is an administrative account, CSRF can compromise the entire web application.

(highlighting added)