# Login doesn’t work and it redirects again to login page in magento 2 using jmeter

Tags: magento2, login, testing, response, jmeter

I am new to `JMeter`. I tried to record login or sign-up using the `JMeter` proxy in `Magento 2.2.7` and I tried to view the result in the `JMeter`, but in `JMeter`. I'm unable to get the response of the login page success.
Please find the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you sending incorrect (recorded?) [`form_key` parameter](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59153/what-is-the-form-key-used-for).

You need to extract this `form_key` from the previous response using i.e. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor):

[image]

and replace recorded value of the `form_key` request parameter with the appriate JMeter Variable:

[image]

Don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan

Once done you should be able to log in successfully:

[image]

More information: [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites/)

Comment: I followed the link.It worked for me. https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41882/login-doesn-t-work-and-it-redirects-again-to-login-page-in-magento-2-using-jmete/41901#41901