# "Invalid Form Key, please refresh the page? " - addtocart

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart, cookie, form-key, jmeter

I am testing website deployed based on Magenta Template Framework, the problem that occurred is that the cart kept being empty even the add to cart link has been ran. And furthermore, i kept getting the error "invalid form key please refresh key".

Variable that has been extarcted, PHPSESID, Formkey and coded using cookie manager.
[image: Here is the extracted key]

The error is still occuring.
[image: This is the error i kept getting]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your JMeter script doesn't provide correct [`form_key` parameter](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59153/what-is-the-form-key-used-for), it is being used by Magento for protection from [CSRF attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) so you need to

1. Extract this `form_key` value from the previous response and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Replace previous (recorded/hard-coded) value with the variable from the step 1

Here how it looks like at i.e. [Magento Online Demo instance](http://demo-m2.bird.eu/customer/account/login/):

[image]

and here is how you can extract it using i.e. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor)

[image]

More information: [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites)

Comment: I have extracted the form key from the main page and insert the form key using the cookie manager. But the error still occured, i have updated my posting with the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Open the console tab in your browser's developer tools and check if a CORS error has occurred. If there is a CORS error, please add the address to the csp white list... This is the most frequent cause in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with magento 2.3, where **Add to Cart** button refreshed the page instead of adding anything in cart. where as website was working properly in **Private Browsing** on a custom theme.

**Solutions Didn't Worked:**

- Change max_input_var=10000
- max_input_time = 600
- max_execution_time = 3600
- Flush cache

**Solution Worked for me:**

In Configuration >> Web, I:

- change **baseURL** from **http://www.domain.com** to **http://domain.com**
- change **Secure Base URL** from **https://www.domain.com** to **https://domain.com**
- Flush cache

I am not sure if its a reliable fix or a temporary, but it resolved the issue for now.